# Why didn't the Ministry just check their left arms to see if they were Death Eaters?

Tags: harry-potter, death-eaters

If the Dark Mark was branded on the left forearm of all the Death Eaters, then why didn't the Ministry just check their arms? That would prove if they were under the Imperious curse or not.

Comment: For that matter, why didn't the Ministry require short sleeve robes. Then everyone could see a dark mark.

Comment: How does having the mark prove you are a voluntary deatheater instead of one under the Imperius curse? I don't understand the logic behind the question, surely somebody Imperius'd to become a death eater could get the dark mark?

Comment: And I don't think the imperius curse gives you a dark mark. But agreed, it's not a bad question for catching voluntary death eaters... unless of course there was a spell to hide it

Comment: Also, short sleeve robes aren't that great in winter. :p

Comment: @Laith He wouldn't have branded the ones under the imperious curse. He wouldn't have wanted everyday wizards and witches being able to apperate to him when he called his Death Eaters.   >"The werewolf might be allowed to wear Death Eater robes when they wanted to use him, but only Voldemort's inner circle were branded with the Dark Mark: Greyback had not been granted this highest honour."

Comment: While not cannon, the fanfic Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationlity  touched on the subject.  There the Dark Marks were normally invisible unless a Death Eater was caught red-handed.  And magical censorship prevented even Snape from discussing that aspect until the censorship was speculated upon as part of a way to detect Death Eaters itself (becoming a liability, dissipating the censorship)