Why didn’t MoM arrest everyone with Death Eater tattoo?
After Voldemort vanished, why wasn’t existence of tattoo used against Death Eaters to arrest them? It was a known fact that Death Eaters used tattoo on their hands to communicate.

There seems to be some kind of a plot hole around the reason why peope with a Dark Mark weren't automatically prosecuted, see for instance: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174842/ . Some pieces of exposition seem to indicate that the existence of the tattoo wasn't known to the MoM well into HP4. On the other hand, the information should have been available to them thanks to people like Snape and Karkaroff, if not by looking at the convicts (which raises the separate question of how much of the Mark is visible after Voldemort's first defeat).

People without a Death Mark being prosecuted is explained by the fact that only a limited number of Voldemort's followers, the highest-ranking ones, were branded (I use the term "follower" deliberately because at the moment I can't figure out when exactly the term "Death Eater" applies, and I believe it might be besides the point).

I closed your question, as it seems to be fundamentally asking the same think as the linked question. If you feel it is not a duplicate, you can edit to clarify, and it may be reopened.

I can't add these to the duplicate list since they don't have an answer, but worth linking them: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/261164/if-all-death-eaters-have-tattoo-on-their-hands-why-is-it-difficult-to-capture-t?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/193479/why-didnt-the-ministry-just-check-their-left-arms-to-see-if-they-were-death-eat?noredirect=1&lq=1

I should add that, while secondary sources (by which I went in my previous comment) claim that only the closest of Voldemort's followers were branded with a Dark Mark, one of the answers in the duplicate cites a passage of HP5 where Hermione suggest that not having a Death Mark could be used as proof that Srius Black isn't a Death Eater. That would be a wrong claim if Sirius being hierarchically inferior to a "branded" Death Eater and still a servant of Voldemort's were a possibility.

Any wizard who was caught after the fact could simply claim to have been magically compelled to get the tattoo.

Ron gave an involuntary shudder.
“Years back, there were a lot of witches and wizards being controlled by the Imperius Curse,” said Moody, and Harry knew he was talking about the days in which Voldemort had been all-powerful. “Some job for the Ministry, trying to sort out who was being forced to act, and who was acting of their own free will.
Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire


"A wizard made me do it"

After the First Wizarding War, Lucius was able to avoid imprisonment by claiming he was under the Imperius

See Harry Potter Fandom Lucius Malfoy .
Its not a crime to join
Not only that but there are some non-magical reasons too, lets look at one of the inspirations for death eaters (the KKK).

It is not a crime in the US and the UK to be a member of a hate group. Just look at the KKK. Despite the fact that the KKK is a hate group that was founded by a bunch of people so they could band together to murder, rob, or other wise punish people who aren't white that step out of their proper place. It still exists, and people are not arrested for belonging to it.

Individual members of the KKK have been arrested when proven that they committed a crime. But the use of masks (much like the death eaters) makes it hard to identify the people who committed a crime. And:

A lot of Wizards are bigotted against muggles. This is seen again, and again throughout the books. google 'mudblood'

Much like how KKK members have been able to get away with crimes because no one looked hard into the crime. Death Eaters were able to get away with crimes due to the high percentage of wizards who weren't interested in punishing a wizard because of their crimes against muggles. Yes it happened.
Look at how little even pro-muggle wizards such as the Weasleys know about muggles...

While his hair may be luscious, his name is Lucius..

Being a death eater appears to be an actual crime

I don't know how this passive-membership subtlety sits with the fact that by the end of the 1st Wizard War Barty Crouch had authorized use of offensive force on suspicion of collaboration with Voldemort and urestricted lethal force on dark wizards. It seems to me that they were going full martial law against a terrorist organization, possibly with some proportionality of sentences for the people who were actually tried (provided that trials in the WW seem to be "either a slap on the hand or a life sentence"). Do you have a source backing up this distinction, other than an analogy?
